# Joomla 3.3.3 error after logout

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I need to install Joomla on a webserver - first, I wasn't able to install Joomla on my remote webserver, because the installation wasn't able to complete step 1 (don't know why), so I installed it on my local computer and uploaded the finished installation on my webserver. So, everything was fine and I now I have a "working" joomla on my webserver.

BUT: I can log in with my admin username and password and so on, but when I click "logout" I get a blank page, only an empty body-tag.

Looking at the error.log file:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 3094558001 bytes) in [...]/www/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php on line 706
```

Everytime I want to open the start page, this error is appending to the log file. I googled and searched stackoverflow, but dind't find any solution.

The allowed memory size of this webserver seems to be 128MB, and the script wants to allocate about 3GB? For me this looks like the joomla developers did a bad job here, but I don't know. The funny thing is, when I google that error message, there are a lot ( ! ) of websites that are not working because of that error.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

OK I just commented out the few lines of code there and it seems that everything works fine now. So if somebody has the same problem as me, just comment out that few lines and hopefully it works too!

Lines 702-713

```
// Convert decimal
/*$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/m', function($m)
{
    return utf8_encode(chr($m[1]));
}, $source
);

// Convert hex
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mi', function($m)
{
    return utf8_encode(chr('0x' . $m[1]));
}, $source
);*/
```

Comment: which file did you comment these lines of code from?  This could potentially cause bigger head aches down the road.

Comment: No, the problem is not those lines, the problem is somethng else probably the same thing that caused you not to be able to install. Do not comment out lines in the core libraries.  Whne you say you couldn't install what exactly happened? HOw did you try to install? Did you have a database created?

Comment: @BrianBolli, as I said: libraries/joomla/filter/input.php

I uploaded the complete joomla 3.3.3 (Full Stable version) to my webserver and opened the installation in Firefox. I entered the sitename, site description, admin-email, password etc. - but when I click next, the blue progressbar appears for a second, disappears and nothing happens. Installation got stuck there I think. Then I installed joomla on my local computer, and uploaded the finished installation to my webserver. Seems to work :))